# How to define mobile website on server

Tags: mobile, indexing

I found this [great tutorial](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=127) that explains designing a mobile website and I've decided to give it a try.  My question is how do I define mobile pages on my server so that they do not conflict or show up on the desktop version of my site. For instance, in the video they use index.html, but since I obviously already have an index.html on my server how would I get a mobile device to direct to a "mobile index" page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to employ browser or device detection techniques. A few ways you can do this is via JavaScript, PHP, or if you're using Wordpress, you could use a plugin.

CSS-Tricks has a nice little snippet that may be useful to you:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/redirect-mobile-devices/

Or if you want to learn the PHP or WordPress side of things, heres another good link:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/mobile-browser-detection/

Answer (score 0):

Its not a server thing. Try messing around with the user agent to detect a device.

Another option is detecting a screen resolution (small sizes > mobile page, big sizes > desktop page. It really depends on layout though).